# Angular2 Component can't access class property inside template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code:
`post.component.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { JobsService } from '../jobs.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'job-post',
  templateUrl: './create.template.html',
  providers: [JobsService]
})

export class JobPostComponent {
  job: any = {};
  errorMessage: String;

  constructor(private _router:Router, private _jobsService:JobsService) {}

  create() {
    this._jobsService
      .create(this.job)
      .subscribe(createdJob => this._router.navigate(['/jobs', createdJob._id]), error => this.errorMessage = error);
  }
}
```

`create.template.html`

```
<h1>Post New Job</h1>
<form (ngSubmit)="create()" novalidate>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="isExtensible">Is Extensible</label>
    <input type="checkbox" required [(ngModel)]="job.isExtensible" name="isExtensible" id="isExtensible">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="isOpenEnded">Open Ended</label>
    <input type="checkbox" required [(ngModel)]="job.isOpenEnded" name="isOpenEnded" id="isOpenEnded">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <contract-type></contract-type>
  </div>
</form>
```

and bellow is another component `contract-type.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'contract-type',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="contractTypes">
      <label class="form-control-label" for="contractType">Contract Type</label>
      <select id="contractType" name="contractType" required [(ngModel)]="job.contractType" class="form-control">
         <option value="0">Select an item</option>
         <option *ngFor="let contractType of contractTypes" value="contractType.name_en">{{ contractType.name_en }}</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    `
})

export class ContractTypeComponent {
  private contractTypes;
  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this._http.get('/api/contractTypes')
      .subscribe(function(res){
         this.contractTypes = res.json();
         console.log(this.contractTypes)
      });
  }
}
```

and the console is like this:[image]
But on browser it is not any dropdown, and if i remove `*ngIf` from div it shows an error `can not read property <contractTypes> of undefined`.
And story is like this, that i need a dropdown list that populated from api response, inside the `create.template.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Add interaction between your components like this:
inside your parent component 'create.template.html':

```
<contract-type [job]="job"></contract-type>
```

and inside your `conract-type.component.ts`:
first import `Input`:
    import { Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
Then change your component class to this:

```
export class ContractTypeComponent {
  private contractTypes;
  @Input() job;
  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this._http.get('/api/contractTypes')
     .subscribe((res)=>{
       this.contractTypes = res.json();
       console.log(this.contractTypes)
    });
  }
}
```